# GIT-TF giving me an illegal proxy URL

Tags: git-tf

I am trying to make a copy of a TFS respository as a GIT repo. I was searching around and it looked like git-tf was a tool that could do this for me. The problem I am having is I am constantly getting this error `git-tf: Illegal proxy URL: 'http://%USER%:%PASSWORD%@%SERVER%:%PORT%'`

I have tried the following commands and get this error:

```
git-tf clone --deep http://BoxNameHere/tfs/ProjNameHere/ $/Proj
git-tf clone --deep https://user:password@BoxNameHere:443/tfs/ProjNameHere/  $/Proj
```

I am stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you have a proxy set somewhere  ? you can try clearing the proxy config

```
export http_proxy=
export https_proxy=
export HTTPS_PROXY=
export HTTP_PROXY=
```

to clear any environment variables that might be set.

Comment: Looks like that was the problem. I had an environment variable named HTTP_PROXY with value http://%USER%:%PASSWORD%@%SERVER%:%PORT%. I am not sure if that comes out of the box with windows or if I made it at some point. After removing it, that error went away.